# why do i run artisan php always produce finished?

Tags: laravel

Every time I do an order php artisan, it always produces "finished".

```
bromindo-3:firecek_web bromindo$ composer dumpautoload
Generating optimized autoload files
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Console\Kernel" was found in both "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/firecek_web/app/Console/Kernel.run.php" and "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/firecek_web/app/Console/Kernel.php", the first will be used.
Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
    You can run './vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon' to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
“finished”
Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
bromindo-3: firecek_web bromindo$ php artisan --optimize:clear
"finished"
```

Comment: I see you run `composer dumpautoload` not `php artisan` ?

Comment: @Ivan, look above `"finished"`.

Comment: Try again without `--` at `optimize:clear`

Comment: I've tried using -- at optimize:clear it's the same

Comment: Could you post that console output as text?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your command is wrong, you should use:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Without `--` in front of optimize, and make sure that you don't have `dd('finished')` somewhere in your code so it won't print that :)

Comment: can't, it will produce "finished"

Comment: you have dump and die "finished" somewhere in your code so Search for that in your IDE. And there is no command `--optimize:clear`. Just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

Search in your code for the word `finished`. use `grep` on linux or `grepwin` on windows.

The word doesnt have to be in a `var_dump()` or a `dd()`. it can also be some plain text in one of the config files on in `public/index.php`...etc

for example `config/app.php`

```
....
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
    ],
];
?>
finished
```